# Can we bypass validation from Xtext project build workflow

Tags: xtext

I Want validator to be called from other classes with out using @Check(annotation) methods in Validator Class.

I want tool to throw error/warning/info using my own class which extends AbstractDeclarativeValidator.

Is it possible to bypass the workflow of xtext and call the MyDSLValidator from our own classes?

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise about "the place" you want to call the validator. Are you aware of @Check(EXPENSIVE) and the corresponding entry in the context menu.

Comment: And you should have a look at the general concept of markers in eclipse